# Is it possible to output this integer as float of the following form using printf?

Tags: bash

In a script, I store the accumulated time in ms from executing several commands in a variable, lets call it `total_elapsed_Time`. This contains e.g. values like

```
1001
```

or

```
12
```

Now, what I want is to output this value in the following form (the time in s with training milliseconds)

```
1.001
```

for the first value,

```
0.012
```

for the second value. At the moment, I do it like this

```
printf '%d.%03d s' "$((total_elapsed_time / 1000))" "$((total_elapsed_time % 1000))"
```

This is okay, and seems to work but I wonder if there is no easier way (so that I only needs to pass the variable to printf and printf takes care of formatting the number).

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in 1001 12 1 10 100 1000 10000 ; do
    x=00$x                              # Prepend two zeros, so we can safely
    x=${x:0: -3}.${x: -3}               # insert the dot on the third position from right.
    printf '%.3f\n' $x
done
```